# How to respond to people who consider vegetarianism "different" or "weird"?

Tags: outreach

Many people I encounter and eat with aren't used to vegetarianism and how do I handle them when they look at me funny when I can't order the meat at the BBQ place, for example?

Comment: Are you basically asking this question: http://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/269/how-can-i-communicate-ideas-about-vegetarianism-or-veganism-to-others-without-ap/ Or are you asking about ways for yourself to cope with it?

Comment: @RamonMelo Please do not answer in comments, especially if the topic has been closed. Comments are to ask for clarification or make suggestions to improve the post; but comments do not have the features to vet whatever you say here.

Answer (score 5):

Vegetarianism is a choice and many people don't understand it. You can appeal to them and say that it is *your* choice and they aren't affected by it in anyway, so they should stop worrying so much about other peoples' lives.

When some of my friends wonder about or insult my vegetarianism, I usually just shrug it off and say, "Yup, I don't eat meat anymore. So what?" And that's usually the end of it. 
Sometimes, I'll tell them that if they have questions about it, I'm happy to answer them, but I'm not going to force them to avoid meat when I'm around and I won't make them feel bad about it.

You can also check out [No Meat Athlete Radio](http://www.nomeatathlete.com/radio-archive/) a podcast where they sometimes talk about the Vegetarian/Vegan community and how they deal with "aggressive" meat-eaters who think we're all just a bunch of idiots.